# Limit number of message process attempts in Azure storage queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

I need to keep track of how many failed attempts have been made to process a message in an azure storage queue and delete the message after N unsuccesful attempts.

I have searched, but have not found any particular property that does this automaticaly and was wondering if there was a way other than using a counter in a storage table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each cloud queue message has a DequeueCount property. Does this help?

REST API reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-messages).

As for how to delete messages automatically after *n* attempts: There's nothing that automatically does this. You'll need to implement your own poison-message handling in Windows Azure queues, based on DequeueCount.

Alternatively, Azure Service Bus queues have a dead-letter queue for undeliverable messages (or ones that can't be processed). More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues).

Comment: Thanks!, that was it... I had seen something of the sort a while back but could not for the life of me remember or find it. It is a metadata property right? So I just check before processing a message and if its over the established limit, I'll delete it.

Comment: Right - each message has its own DequeueCount - it will initially equal 1 the first time you get a message from the queue.